# How do I un-format my Python code using a keybind or function in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want this:

```
variable = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three"
}
```

To become this:

```
variable = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}
```

Without having to manually backspace and remove the extra new lines.

Comment: Do you mean inside your editor/IDE?

Comment: What editor are you using? Some may offer this functionality. Or you can just use a regular expression in your editor's find/replace dialog: replace `\s+` (a run of whitespace) with a single space, being sure to tell your editor to use multiline mode and constrain replacement to the selection. Be careful if you have multiple spaces inside quotes, though.

Comment: im using VScode, also thanks kindall for that tip, ill use it for now unless theres a VScode feature / plugin that does it faster

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Python specific question. Also depends in your IDE.

Generally, you can try to use a formatter such as [Python Black](https://github.com/psf/black).

Also many tools/IDEs offer their own code reformatters/beautifiers.
Since you're using VSCode, have a look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting).